# AttributeError 'RegisterDetailView' object has no attribute 'get_object'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to submit a PATCH for an existing record via curl.

I want to change my Boolean field from true to false.

The primary key is not the default id, but a CharField defined in my models.py I did this hoping to make the url path easier to manipulate; /api/register/serial number vs id number.

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Register(models.Model):
    system_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    request = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.serial_number
```

### views.py

```
class RegisterDetailView(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.RegisterSerializer
    def get(self, pk):
        return Register.objects.get(pk=pk)

    def patch(self, request, pk):
        registermodel_object = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = serializers.RegisterSerializer(registermodel_object, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors,
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from register import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^register/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', views.RegisterDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

### curl command

```
curl -d "system_type=switch&serial_number=SAL1834ZDSY&ip_address=f8c2.8887.d480&mac_address=172.16.24.11&request=false" -X PATCH http://192.168.1.100/api/register/SAL1834ZDSY/
```

When I run my curl command using patch I get this error:

```
AttributeError at /api/register/SAL1834ZDSY/
'RegisterDetailView' object has no attribute 'get_object'

Request Method: PATCH
Request URL: http://192.168.1.100/api/register/SAL1834ZDSY/
Django Version: 2.2.6
Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path: ['.', '', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/opt/django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/opt/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time: Sun, 24 Nov 2019 02:29:22 +0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is no `get_object` method in `APIView` - you have to manually fetch object.

If you want to build endpoint with both `get` and `patch` methods and handle single instance, you should extend [`RetrieveUpdateAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdateapiview).

Should look like this:

```py
class RegisterDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Register.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. All those lines down just the two in the class. Simply fantastic